# CoreAnimation keeping track of origin values

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm facing really often requirement to animate a view and animate it back to its origin value. (Something like zooming in a `UIImageView` on `Tap` and back)

Is there a more elegant solution to keep track of the origin values instead of creating class fields and assigning those on `viewDidLoad`?

How do you guys handle such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a transform to the view you can just set it back to the identity transform when you're done. This code creates a basic toggle that scales up and down.

```
// Check to see if the current transform is identity which means
// no transform applied. If it is, scale the view. Otherwise, 
// set it back to identity.
CGFloat scale = 3.0f;
if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity([_imageView transform])) {
  [_imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)];
} else {
  [_imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
}
```

This keeps you from having to keep track of what the starting value was.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Matt, are there functions like identity transform for frames and so? This would be a smart solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A change to the frame as a transform would be the scale transform. If you want to move x and y, you could use a translation transform instead, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y).

Comment: I think I got you here. My approach of moving seems very verbose here. (Creating new rect, assigning it to view.frame etc.) Your suggestion makes sense here Matt. Thanks for this.

Comment: However, if your view's transform is not the identity transform then the view's frame property is not defined, and you need to use bounds and center to read/write the view's size and position instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution of keeping track of the initial origin values in the class is exactly the way I do it. No inelegance there, just something you have to do. I'm not aware of any other solution.